# pythonの2次元行列中の要素の判断

Tags: python

下のliは2次元配列で、6行3列の行列を表しおり、2～5行目の2列目がすべて0であることを判断したいです。

```
li=[[1,1,1],
    [2,0,1],
    [3,0,1],
    [4,0,1],
    [5,0,1],
    [6,1,1]]

count=0
row1=2
row2=5
col=2
for i in range(row1-1,row2):
    if li[i][col-1]==0:count+=1

if count==row2+1-row1:
    print("All 0")
```

一応結果は出るのですがもう少し良い方法は無いでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

```
if all([item[col-1] == 0 for item in li[row1-1:row2]]):
  print("All 0")
```

でしょうか。前提条件は `row2 >= row1` です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決できました。